# Value of $q$ for which function is convex or concave

Tags: calculus

> If $f(x)=px^{q}$, $p,q>0$. Then find value of $q$ for which function $f(x)$ is convex or concave.

What I tried: $f'(x)=pqx^{q-1}$ and $f''(x)=pq(q-1)x^{q-2}$.

Now if the function is convex, then $f''(x)=pq(q-1)x^{q-2}>0\Longrightarrow (q-1)x^{q-2}>0$.

So the function is convex when $q>1$ and function is concave If $q<1$.

Can anyone please tell me is my process is right. If not Then how do I solve it. Help me please. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming that the domain of $f$ is $(0,\infty)$ what you have done is correct. (For $q=1$ it is both concave and convex).

Comment: Thanks Professor. But i did not understand why for $q=1$ it is concave upward or Concave Downward both. Because for $q=1.$ we have $f''(x)=0$

Comment: Thanks Professor Got it.